# How to migrate users? (Symfony + FOSUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to migrate from an old to a new system with the following specifications:

**Old System**:

- Symfony 2.7
- FOSUserBundle ~2.0@dev

**New System**:

- Symfony 3.0.5
- FOSUserBundle 2.0.x-dev

The `parameters.secret` of `app/config/parameters.yml` is the same.

**Problem**: After copying the old `fos_user`-table to the new DB, I'm not able to login anymore.

Probably caused by a new way of generating the **salt** and **password**, because:

I'm able to login, if I replace the salt and password of an old user by the salt and password of a new user, generated by the new system (via DataFixtures).

How can I migrate the users without forcing them to change their password?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you *really* migrating from FOS 2.0.0 to 2.0.0-alpha3?

Comment: @AlexRockAncelet `composer.json` says `2.0.x-dev`; last entry in  `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Changelog.md` is `2.0.0-alpha3`.

Comment: @AlexRockAncelet I updated the versions. It's what I've found in my `composer.json`-files.

Comment: Don't use FOSUser's dev versions, now we have a 2.0.0 stable version, keep this one, future updates will contain only bug fixes and translations. You should rely only to the 2.0.0 version.
For the rest, there shouldn't be any problem migrating to 2.0.0 as you can see in the last changelog from 2.0.0...master => 
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/compare/v2.0.0...master